# Utilizing dynamic email content in a POST request for a push notification

Tags: google-app-engine, email, rest, post, push-notification

I am an iOS developer wading into pretty unfamiliar territory. I have a client who wants to utilize the body of an email, the content of which is dynamic items (like name, address, GPS coordinates) and utilize that information as part of a push notification.

Essentially I need to figure out a way how to get the body of the email, parse the contents for these common items, take those items and make a POST request to initiate a push notification to my app (likely using the REST API from Parse).

Some options i've considered. Writing a server-side app which monitors for new emails, parses the body and generates the code and makes the POST request (but im not sure exactly how).

Using Google's App Engine and creating a script of some sort and using gmail (not sure exactly how to do that).

Im hoping someone out there has some ideas about how to accomplish this in a somewhat streamlined and elegant fashion.  Input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the `MailService` in Google AppEngine to help you address your requirements. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/).

The service provides an ability to receive email that is sent to your application. Refer to the link here for Java: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving. If you are using Python, you can get the same from the Python Docs. The incoming mail service will allow you to write a simple handler/servlet that can get invoked every time you receive an email. You can parse out the email content and create your Push Notification data.

Alternately, instead of doing everything synchronously - you could break it up by:
1) Receive the email and create a Task
2) The Task sends off the Push Notification

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you break it down a bit further? So I write an app in Python (or Java) which is deployed to the Google App Engine.  Does this app run all the time? Meaning anytime an email is sent to example@handlerapp.com the content is parsed and the POST request made? I'm trying to get my mind around this conceptually...

Comment: Yes. To keep it simple for now, you can assume that once you have deployed the application to App Engine, your application is available. It might not be running but Google creates an instance for you to process any requests. So for all practical purposes, assume that it is running. Now when the email comes in, Google will package the email and make a HTTP POST to your SErvlet/Handler. The code you keep in your Servlet is then invoked. That is the flow at a high level for the incoming email.

Comment: Can you use MailService to parse the emails of any gmail user. So for instance, Jony Doe signs up for my app and oAuths in. His email is jony.doe@gmail.com. Then my app parses all incoming emails for a specific criteria and archives them?

Comment: It is not about the Mail Service. But as part of the Mail Handler, you will get a Mime Message object and you can parse/inspect all the Email Headers and the Content, which means you can inspect the email address, the from, the to, subject and body. You can then execute the rest of your code. Hope this helps.